# Combine two mod_rewrite rule into one

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to combine two mod_rewrite rules into one.

1) In CMS, there is index.php that handles all queries on the web. For example if URI is domain.com/query-string, index.php call/include needed parts and displey content. I do this with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[[:alnum:]]+$
RewriteRule ^([^*]+) index.php [L,QSA]
```

2) I need to redirect with HTTP 301 Moved permanently www to non-www. For example www.domain.com to domain.com. I do this with:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

But when I put both these rules into htaccess file, it stops work and all links, that are on the web redirect do index.php and show homepage. That is why, I need to combine these two rules into one.

In the beginning of .htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

Is there any solution, how to do it?

Whole .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[[:alnum:]]+$
RewriteRule ^([^*]+) index.php [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I have tried to reorder rules, but with no solution.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should show your whole .htaccess (at least -- rewriting rules part, but all of them). Very likely the issue is in order of the rules (taking into account those that you have provided so far -- they should be in 3-2-1 order)

Comment: I have added whole htaccess to the first post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct order. based on the information provided so far I see no reason why this should not work (works here on test machine). If it still does not work -- then maybe there is another rule somewhere else (or redirect is made in your PHP app).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[[:alnum:]]+$
RewriteRule ^([^*]+) index.php [L,QSA]
```

**BTW**, if you matching `%{HTTP_HOST}` with regular expression (pattern starts with `^`) then it's better to escape dots, as in some circumstances it can make huge difference (maybe not in your case, but still, since dot means "any character") -- `^www\.domain\.com`. Alternatively use plain string comparison instead of regex: `=www.domain.com`